# Detect home page in Magento .phtml that will work with BLOCK_HTML cache enabled

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I have tried the following two methods in catalog/navigation/vert_nav.phtml to add or suppress content specific to the home page:

```
if($this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true))):
```

or

```
if(
Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  &&
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' 
) :
```

Both work fine, however when BLOCK_HTML cache is turned on, it works at first, then after a while the home page starts displaying content that is intended only for other pages (after an else clause I use lower down). When I turn off the BLOCK_HTML, it behaves as expected.

Interestingly I've used the same code (the 1st one) in page/html/head.phtml (for home page specific javascript/css), and in page/html/header.phtml (for a header banner that should only appear on the home page), and these work fine even when BLOCK_HTML is ON.

(Magento 1.4.1.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above answer is the best solution.

You could simply copy app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Nagivation.php

to:

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Nagivation.php

and then change the getCacheKeyInfo() method as described above.

```
/**
 * Get Key pieces for caching block content
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $shortCacheId = array(
        'CATALOG_NAVIGATION',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
        'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
        'name' => $this->getNameInLayout(),
        $this->getCurrenCategoryKey(),
        // Your logic to make home/none home have different cache keys
        Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' ? '1' : '0'
    );
    $cacheId = $shortCacheId;

    $shortCacheId = array_values($shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = implode('|', $shortCacheId);
    $shortCacheId = md5($shortCacheId);

    $cacheId['category_path'] = $this->getCurrenCategoryKey();
    $cacheId['short_cache_id'] = $shortCacheId;

    return $cacheId;
}
```

This will make the cache key different for homepage / none-homepage pages, which will cache two copies, rather than caching a single template copy for use on all pages.

Comment: great addition to my post, there's just a little typo in this line: `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' ? '1', '0'` - should be `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home' ? '1': '0'` to work correctly

Comment: thanks for that, it was typed directly into the browser with no testing :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are sources you'd want to read about Block Html cache:

1. [magento forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput)
2. [some blog](http://wabism.com/magento-bypass-caching-for-individual-block/)
3. [inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-block-caching/)

It would be better for performance to not disable the block completely, but rather specify the cache key in a smart way. So here's what you should do:

1. First - specify a custom block for your .phtml file. If you don't know what Block is, or how to assign a block to a template file, [here's](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates) the reference to Alan Storm blog.
2. Second - you will have to add next code to a Block constructor:

   ```
   $this->addData(array(
       'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
       'cache_tags'     => array(Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG),
       'cache_key'      => $this->getCacheKey(),
   ));
   ```

   As you see, I used here the `getCacheKey` method from the abstract class `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.
3. Now you need to make sure the cache_key works for your logic. The `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getCacheKey` uses other method, which should actually specify the unique values for our block - `getCacheKeyInfo`. You need to redefine it using your logic:

   ```
   public function getCacheKeyInfo()
   {
       $isHomepage = 0;
       if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home') {
           $isHomepage = 1;
       }
       return array(
           $this->getNameInLayout(),
           $isHomepage,
       );
   }
   ```

   Now you can be sure that cache key for Home Page will differ from cache key to all other your pages, and your cache will return valid info.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I ended up selecting Andrew's answer instead since this was a quick fix that worked with a template I hadn't originally authored.

Answer (score 2):

We use

```
<!-- SNH CUSTOM -->

    $route = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName();

    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getActionName();

if($route == 'cms' && $action == 'index'):

    <div class="grid_12">

        echo $this->getChildHtml('shopper_footer_partners');

    </div>

endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to these answers suggesting to check if current page identifier equals to "home".

It would be definitely safer to compare it with `Mage::getStoreConfig('web/default/cms_home_page')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

really the best way is to:

1 Update your layout XML (local.xml or theme custom.xml)

```
<!--  CUSTOM: ADD NEW FOOTER BLOCK AT BOTTOM FOR PARTNERS -->
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="footer">
    <block type="cms/block" name="footer_block_extra">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_block_extra</block_id></action>
    </block>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

and step 2 add this code where you want the block in your template phtml (often /page/html/footer.phtml)

```
<!-- SNH CUSTOM -->
<div class="grid_12">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('footer_block_extra'); ?>
</div>
```

and step 3 create a new CMS block in your backend with the ID "footer_block_extra" ... and add your content.