# Magento 1.7 If Home Page Condition in .phtml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2 and I stuck in a problem and google out all solutions but not work for me...

my question is I want to add in my 2Column-left.phtml layout If conditions.
Like i.e. I want to show this content If I am on Home Page

```
                **<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sectionA') ?></div>**

                <div class="product-content section-content-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-left sidebar">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and this if I am not on Home Page:

```
                <div class="product-content section-content-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-left sidebar">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>


                **<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sectionA') ?></div>**

                    </div>
                </div>
```

I used all solution like:

http://dltr.org/blog/magento/187/Magento-How-to-find-if-you-are-on-homepage-getIsHomePage

[Detect home page in Magento .phtml that will work with BLOCK_HTML cache enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403675/detect-home-page-in-magento-phtml-that-will-work-with-block-html-cache-enabled)

but not working... please help and suggest what should i need to do or Do i am making an error???

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if($action=='cms_index_index'){
    echo "home";?>

    <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sectionA') ?></div>**
<?php } ?>

                <div class="product-content section-content-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-left sidebar">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**non home page:**

```
<div class="product-content section-content-2">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-left sidebar">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

<?php 
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if($action!='cms_index_index'){ ?>
<div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sectionA') ?></div>
<?php } ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your answer. Can this be if or else condition? i just want to reorder my section according to If home page or else...

Comment: not working amit, its shows this error   "  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\wamp\www\flavours\app\design\frontend\flavours\default\template\page\2columns-left.phtml on line 60  "

Answer (score 1):

In Header phtml file:

```
if($this->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'You are in Homepage!';
} else {
    echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
}
```

In Other phtml files:

```
 if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
            echo 'You are in Homepage!';
        } else {
            echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at how Magento handles this. Line 46 in the class **Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header** shows:

```
 /**
 * Check if current url is url for home page
 *
 * @return true
 */
public function getIsHomePage()
{
    return $this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
}
```